# Understanding Firebase firestore rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want setup my firebase rulse . I want register users according to their district and my **District** stored in my firestore database . So when on user going to register but that user not logged in to the app so i want setup my rules like Any one can read **District** Collection and other collection must be authentication

so i setup my rules like this is it correct ?

```
rules_version = '2';
  service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
       match /{document=**} {
         allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
        }
       match /District/{document=**}  {
          allow read :if true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules should do what you suggest -- allow unauthenticated reads to anything in `/District` and allow authenticated users the ability to read and write the entire database.

Three things though:

First, you should familiarize yourself with the [simulation ability](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules#simulator) of the rules console.  It lets you directly test specific scenarios by hand, to explore what is going on in your rules.

Second, Firebase provides a way to write [tests for security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) using the emulator.  This is good practice to ensure that you have a comprehensive suite of tests that is repeatable as your application grows in complexity.

Finally, realize that even with this set of rules, you have given any authenticated user the full run of the database -- they can literally read or write any data without restriction (this is definately [not a recommended configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules#access_for_any_authenticated_user)).  This would include, for example, deleting the entire `/District` collection.  This may or may not be acceptable for your use case, but you should consider the choice very carefully.  Keep in mind that users are able to run *arbitrary* code against your database (not just the code of your client app), subject only to the permissions granted by security rules.